# Slice a string using index positions in Elixir

Tags: string, elixir

In Ruby, I can go:

```
"Sergio"[1..-1] #> "ergio"
```

Doing the same in Elixir gives a runtime error:

```
iex(1)> "Sergio"[1..-1]
** (CompileError) iex:1: the Access syntax and calls to Access.get/2 are not available for the value: "Sergio"
```

Also tried:

```
iex(1)> String.slice("Sergio", 1, -1)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in String.slice/3
(elixir) lib/string.ex:1471: String.slice("Sergio", 1, -1)
```

**How can I get a substring from a string in Elixir?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`String.slice/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/String.html#slice/2):

```
iex(1)> String.slice("Sergio", 1..-1)
"ergio"
iex(2)> String.slice("Sergio", 0..-3)                
"Serg"
```

Comment: Realize it's long after the fact but shouldn't that second expression be: `String.slice("Sergio",0..3)` (you've got `-3` there).

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci  In this case -3 and 3 return the same thing. -3 counts from the back, 3 from the front.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get substring without first letter you can use also:

```
"Sergio" |> String.to_charlist() |> tl() |> to_string()
```

And another way to get substring from the end is:

```
a = "Sergio"
len = String.length(a)
String.slice(a, -len + 1, len - 1) # "ergio"
#this -len + 1 is -1(len - 1) and it's exact to Ruby's -1 when slicing string.
```

Comment: Your first method returns a charlist not a string.  You'd want to add `|> to_string()` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `String#slice` there are also other ways to come up with the same result:

```
"Sergio" |> String.split(~r|(?<=\A.)|) |> List.last |> IO.inspect
#=> "ergio"
~r|(?<=\A.).*| |> Regex.run("Sergio") |> List.last |> IO.inspect
#=> "ergio"
```

In this particular case they bring no added value, but in some more complicated cases (as a reference to ruby's `"Sergio"[/.../]` they might have some sense.